# SvelteKit: "Error: request.query has been replaced by request.url.searchParams"

Tags: npm, svelte, sveltekit

I wanted to try out SvelteKit on MacOs 11.5.2. Using node v16.13.1, npm 8.1.2.

I have installed the SvelteKit as per original guidance:

```
npm init svelte@next my-app
cd my-app
npm install
npm run dev -- --open
```

Then, when localhost:3000 opens, I get this error:

```
**Error: request.query has been replaced by request.url.searchParams**
    at Object.get (file:///Web/Svelte_30-12-21/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1753:12)
    at Object.handle (/Web/Svelte_30-12-21/my-app/src/hooks.ts:10:30)
    at respond (file:///Web/Svelte_30-12-21/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1764:30)
    at svelteKitMiddleware (file:///Web/Svelte_30-12-21/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:4577:28)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been introduced in a commit made earlier today and [reported](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/3140). It has been fixed already, run `npm update` or delete your `node_modules` directory and reinstall.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem. In `src/hooks.js` replace

`const method = request.query.get('_method');`

with

`const method = request.method;`

If you are using `npm init svelte@next my-app` and using the demo app, you are also going to run into a problem in `Header.svelte`.

replace

```js
<li class:active={$page.path === '/'}><a sveltekit:prefetch href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class:active={$page.path === '/about'}><a sveltekit:prefetch href="/about">About</a></li>
<li class:active={$page.path === '/todos'}><a sveltekit:prefetch href="/todos">Todos</a></li>
```

with

```js
<ul>
  <li class:active={$page.url.pathname === '/'}><a sveltekit:prefetch href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class:active={$page.url.pathname === '/about'}>
   <a sveltekit:prefetch href="/about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class:active={$page.url.pathname === '/todos'}>
    <a sveltekit:prefetch href="/todos">Todos</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This one also fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case (**SvelteKit next 160**) it was different than in @klequis answer. The `src/hooks.js` contained this block of code

[image: hooks.js sveltekit next 160]

The solution to this is actually removing this if block altogether.

I removed it and I confirmed that this assignment is not needed anymore by logging the output `console.log(request.method)` output: `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Untested code.

```
// TODO https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1046
const searchParams = new URL(event.request.url).searchParams;
if (searchParams.has('_method')) {
    event.request = new Request({ ...event.request, method: searchParams.get('_method').toUpperCase()||''}) ;
}
```